# how to detete checked strings from an arraylist in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <EditText
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/TaskName"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/addBtn"
android:text="Add New Item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="addItems"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
android:text="Delete completed tasks"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="deleteItems"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
/>
```

and this is my java code

```
package com.srk.android.rough1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class Rough1Activity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private EditText taskNameEditText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        taskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TaskName);
    }
    public void addItems(View v) {   
        adapter.add(taskNameEditText.getText().toString());   
    }
    public void deleteItems(View v) {
    }
}
```

The arraylist consists of strings with checkboxes.The items are added using 'Add New Item'button.now what should be the code of my 'deleteItems' method or is there any better way to delete the items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Delete" button that removes the checked rows by using [getCheckedItemPositions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) and [clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29):

```
public void deleteItems(View v) {
    ListView listView = getListView();
    // Get checked row numbers
    SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    // Remove row from highest to lowest index
    for(int index = checked.size() - 1; index > -1; index--)
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(checked.keyAt(index)));

    // Remove checkmarks
    listView.clearChoices();
}
```

Comment: Thank u but it is not working.The application is stopping unexpectedly forcing to close.

Comment: Hmm, I tested this version and it works for me. Please post the logcat in your question.